# How to compile and launch CUDA codes using dynamic parallelism from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, dynamic, cuda

I know how to compile a CUDA code from Matlab, i.e., by compiling to a PTX file and executing by `parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('function name');`

I'm now in a trouble with launching a CUDA code using dynamic parallelism from Matlab.

I was able to manage PTX compilation with the command

> nvcc -ptx DynamicParalell.cu -o DynamicParalell.ptxw64 -rdc=true
>   -lcudadevrt -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=sm_35

The compilation was successful, but if I run the compiled code from Matlab by  `parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('function name');`, I get the following error message:

---

> An error occurred during PTX compilation of . The information
>   log was:
>
> The error log was: ptxas : fatal error : Unresolved extern function
>   'cudaGetParameterBuffer The CUDA error code was:
>   CUDA_ERROR_NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU.

---

People talk about launching dynamic parallelism from Visual Studio, but not from Matlab.

Does anyone know how to do it?

I learned that error message `cudaGetParameterBuffer` has to do with `\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\lib\x64\cudadevrt.dll`, which I already have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but it seems to me that the procedure in [Run CUDA or PTX Code on GPU](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html#bsic5ih-1) will not work if you try to link libraries at the compilation stage, since it requires to work on `.ptx` files which are the result of compilation of `.cu` files having only `__global__` functions. This may be the reason why you have the unresolved extern error when you launch the function from Matlab: you are not really linking the cudadevrt library.

Comment: You may wish to try the procedure in [Compiling CUDA mex files with Visual Studio](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/498). You can easily make a test by the downloadable Visual Studio 2010 project.